# execvp filepath clarification

Tags: c, execvp

I'm writing a shell in C, and I'm having trouble understanding the filepath parameter needed for `execvp(filepath,argv)`.

If the user typed wanted to run `ls -a` in their current directory ... let's say `/home/user1` ... what would be the `filepath` and `argv` for running `ls` in said directory?

Would the `filepath` be the directory for where the command will be executed from `/home/user1` or would it be the command's location `/bin/ls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To run /bin/ls -a in the current directory you would need:**

The same as `argv` passed into `main()` when a C program starts except `NULL` terminated, and path is the same as `argv[0]`.

```
char* argv[] = { "/bin/ls", "-a", NULL };
execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

Comment: One other question after execvp runs like in your example will it automatically print results to terminal or will I have to do something else too?

Comment: It will write to stdout / stderr. So yes you'll see it on terminal.

Answer (score 6):

The `filepath` argument to `execvp()` can take either of two forms — it contains a slash or it does not contain a slash.

#### With slash

The `filepath` argument specifies the pathname of the executable, either an absolute name (starts with slash) or a relative name (does not start with slash, but does contain a slash).  The `execvp()` function makes no changes to the argument, and the program is executed (or not) assuming that the file named exists and is executable.

#### Without slash

The `filepath` arguments specifies a 'simple' name such as `ls`.  The `excevp()` function then seeks to execute a program with the name `ls` found in one of the directories listed in the `$PATH` environment variable.  The `p` in `execvp()` is for 'path', as in path lookup.

#### Applying the theory

If the user types `ls -a` to a shell, the normal way to execute that would be to create an array of character pointers equivalent to:

```
char *argv[] = { "ls", "-a", 0 };

execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

The `execvp()` will now do the path-based analysis and attempt to execute `ls` from one of the directories listed in `$PATH`.

If the user types `/bin/ls -a` to a shell, then the normal way to execute that would be to create an array of character pointers equivalent to:

```
char *argv[] = { "/bin/ls", "-a", 0 };

execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

The `execvp()` will now execute the absolute pathname specified, because that's what the user requested (as opposed to, say, `/usr/bin/ls` or `/usr/local/bin/ls`).

Note that the processing is actually the same — you split the command line into words; each word becomes an element of an array of character pointers that is terminated with a null pointer, and you pass the first word to `execvp()` as the 'filepath' argument, and the whole array as the second argument.

Obviously, a shell can cache the locations of the actual executables, and many shells do, so that `execvp()` doesn't have to do work trying to find the program (and the shells don't call `execvp()` but typically call `execv()` with the absolute pathname of the executable.  But that isn't necessary; it is an optimization.

Note, too, that there is nothing to stop you doing:

```
char *argv[] = { "/honky/tonk/toys", "-a", 0 };
execvp("ls", argv);
```

Now `argv[0]` should be `"/honky/tonk/toys"` and not `ls`, for all it is the `ls` executable that is run.  What you find in `/proc` depends on you having `/proc` on your system (Mac OS X does not support it, for example), but the symlink to the binary should be a link to `/bin/ls`.  On Linux, you're apt to find that `ps` reports the binary name (`ls`), even though `/proc/PID/cmdline` contains the original arguments (so `argv[0]` is `/honky/tonk/toys`).  Whether this is good or not depends on your viewpoint, but all the world is not Linux.

Comment: does that means that for executing a file in current directory we have to give "./filename" as the file path

Comment: If you don't have the current directory on your `$PATH` (either explicitly as `.` or via an absolute pathname, or implicitly by a leading or trailing colon or adjacent colons in the value of PATH), then you need to specify `./filename` to execute the program `filename` in the current directory via `execvp()`.  A plain `execv()` would execute the file in the current directory without the leading `./`, though (but wouldn't find `filename` anywhere else). Example paths with current directory: `PATH=:/bin`, `PATH=/bin:`, `PATH=/bin::/usr/bin`, `PATH=/bin:.`. (There are other arcane possibilities.)

Comment: How does it look for PATH without `envp`? And what if `envp` is changed in the current process?

Comment: @user129393192: The fallback position is to use `getenv("PATH")` — but there is a decent chance that the implementation of `execvp()` is privy to some internal data from the library and can do things differently.  And a shell may well not use the system-provided `execvp()` but use its own variant which allows it to know and cache the path to an executable, which it will use next time unless the cache had to be invalidated.